# Visual GUI designer frameworks for creating custom visual GUI designer

Tags: interface, designer

is there are any GUI designer frameworks/module/library out there for creating custom visual GUI designer (drag-drop component on frame)

almost every time a new language is created, one may have to write a gui designer from scratch (eg freepascal's Lazarus)